# How to disable Angular inputs on toggle

Tags: angular

I am doing inline editing. I want input to be disabled until user clicks edit button, opposite for save button. I am trying to set it `[disabled]="!hidemeSub[index]"` like this but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index">
    <form [formGroup]="rates">
      <div  formGroupName="type">
        <div [hidden]="hidemeSub[index]"
          (click)="hidemeSub[index] = !hidemeSub[index];">Edit</div>
        <div (click)="editRates(item.id, index)" [hidden]="!hidemeSub[index]">Done</div>
        <div formArrayName="options">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="index">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="!hidemeSub[index]" formControlName="rateRangeFrom">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="!hidemeSub[index]" formControlName="rateRangeTo">
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

.ts

```
hidemeSub = {};
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? Also, hidemeSub is an object, you cannot iterate it with index. So, please provide more code from ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[attr.disabled]** instead of **[disabled]**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [attr.disabled]="!hidemeSub[index]" formControlName="rateRangeFrom">
```

And value passed should either hold **true or null**

Simple working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-87nxyh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! yes, but now input is always disabled, it doesnt toggle

Comment: @aelin_galathius I have added a working example to the answer. Can refer to it